# Calling 2 webservices in same php file

Tags: php

I'm looking to call 2 webservices via a single api file, this is what i have at the moment:

```
    <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 

$curl = curl_init();

$apiData = array(
        'FirstName'   => $_POST["FirstName"],
        'LastName'   => $_POST["LastName"],
        'email'   => $_POST["email"],
        'Phone'   => $_POST["phone"],
        'Country' => $_POST["country"],
        'password' => $_POST["password"],
        'jsonResponse' => 'true'
    );

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://my-url.com/api-reg.php",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($apiData),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

I would like to post the same data to another webservice aswell
any tips on implementing this ?

thanks!

Comment: What's stopping you?  What have you tried and what isn't working?  If you know how to invoke a web service, what's stopping you from doing that twice?

Comment: Call one (the first) then call the next one (the second)

Comment: You can just call the second webservice the same way you called the first one. Is your problem in how to combine the results?

Comment: Sorry. Not very experienced with php. Looking for a code exmple as im not very fimilar with the syntax

Comment: What you've posted above is an example.  It is not clear what problem you're having.  Does the above work?  If so, then what difficulty are you having simply making an additional request to a different URL?  If the above is _not_ working, then explain in detail what you _expect_ it to do, and what it is _actually_ doing, and what debugging you have already done.